# Set binary registry setting through GPO

Tags: group-policy, binary, windows-registry

I've got a REG_BINARY registry key that I'd like to set via GPO. However, the GPO interface to add registry settings simply has a 'Value Data' text field.

I can set the type to REG_BINARY, but what format is the text field expecting the data in so that the key is correctly set?

Should I be converting my data to Hex before entering it here, or should I be doing this in a completely different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never personally tested it, but according to [this example](http://sdmsoftware.com/blog/category/security-related/), it should be in Hex format.

Comment: That link is broken.

Comment: You're right. Sorry to hear that, I answered this question long ago and it was active. I can't remember the exact details, however the main point was the value had to be entered in Hex.

Comment: That's why it's important to not just post a link as an answer, but rather either quote or rewrite the content here (with reference) as to preserve and spread the knowledge.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20110528150050/http://sdmsoftware.com/blog/category/security-related/ this appears to be the original link. Unfortunately, no images are available.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bat file to do it and run is as a start up script

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742162(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Please consider either quoting or rewriting the answer here on this site instead of strictly just posting a link for an explaination.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced a similar issue. According to an export of the key, the reg-file consists of the following:

```
"key-value"=hex:01,\
  00,00,00,30,0c,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

In order for the Group Policy Manager to read this data, it should be entered as following. Upper case letter and no commas:

```
01000000300C000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: It's the capitals that made me grit my teeth but in the end I've found that (in my environment at least) case doesn't matter